How to filter elements more precisely?
When I type something into the filter, for example the letter "B", the result shows me <div class="item" with; Ball, Dinosaur "blue" and Robot.
I would like to know how I can make the filter ignore what is inside <span class="tag" and only search inside the <p class="name", so that the final result is only <divs class="item" with; Ball and Robot


$("#filter").on("keyup", function () {
    var value =$(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#box .item").filter(function () {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
#box {
  width: 300px;
}
.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.name {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.tag {
  background: silver;
  padding:2px 4px;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="filter" type="text" placeholder="Filter..." autocomplete="off">
<div id="box">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="img.jpg">
    <p class="name">Radio</p>
    <span class="tag">red</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="img.jpg">
    <p class="name">Ball</p>
    <span class="tag">red</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="img.jpg">
    <p class="name">Dinosaur</p>
    <span class="tag">blue</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="img.jpg">
    <p class="name">Robot</p>
    <span class="tag">blue</span>
  </div>
</div>




FYI String.prototype.includes() is semantically better than indexOf()


Don't use "keydown" eventname. An Input element should also respond to i.e: copy/paste actions etc, not necessarily coming from a keyboard. Instead, use rather the "input" event
Don't use .filter() if there's nothing to filter. Use jQuery's .each() instead
Target the this's .name child using $(".name", this) or $(this).find(".name")

Example:


$("#filter").on("input", function () {
  const value = $(this).val().trim().toLowerCase();
  $("#box .item").each(function () {
    const match = $(".name", this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1;
    $(this).toggle(match);
  });
});
#box {
  width: 300px;
}
.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.name {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.tag {
  background: silver;
  padding:2px 4px;
}
<input id="filter" type="text" placeholder="Filter..." autocomplete="off">
<div id="box">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="img.jpg">
    <p class="name">Radio</p>
    <span class="tag">red</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="img.jpg">
    <p class="name">Ball</p>
    <span class="tag">red</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="img.jpg">
    <p class="name">Dinosaur</p>
    <span class="tag">blue</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="img.jpg">
    <p class="name">Robot</p>
    <span class="tag">blue</span>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



Alternatively, you could inverse the logic in that, you first each #box .name elements, and then toggle the parent .item using .closest()


$("#filter").on("input", function () {
  const value = $(this).val().trim().toLowerCase();
  $("#box .name").each(function () {
    const match = $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1;
    $(this).closest(".item").toggle(match);
  });
});
#box {
  width: 300px;
}
.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.name {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.tag {
  background: silver;
  padding:2px 4px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}
<input id="filter" type="text" placeholder="Filter..." autocomplete="off"><br>
<div id="box">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="img.jpg">
    <p class="name">Radio</p>
    <span class="tag">red</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="img.jpg">
    <p class="name">Ball</p>
    <span class="tag">red</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="img.jpg">
    <p class="name">Dinosaur</p>
    <span class="tag">blue</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="img.jpg">
    <p class="name">Robot</p>
    <span class="tag">blue</span>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



Also, why use an entire library (jQuery) for such a simple task?


const lower = (val) => val?.trim().toLowerCase();

function filterItems (val) {
  document.querySelectorAll("#box .name").forEach(function(elName) {
    const match = lower(elName.textContent).includes(lower(val));
    elName.closest(".item").classList.toggle("hidden", !match);
  });
}

document.querySelector("#filter").addEventListener("input", function () {
  filterItems(this.value);
});
#box {
  width: 300px;
}
.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.name {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.tag {
  background: silver;
  padding:2px 4px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}
<input id="filter" type="text" placeholder="Filter..." autocomplete="off">
<div id="box">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="img.jpg">
    <p class="name">Radio</p>
    <span class="tag">red</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="img.jpg">
    <p class="name">Ball</p>
    <span class="tag">red</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="img.jpg">
    <p class="name">Dinosaur</p>
    <span class="tag">blue</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="img.jpg">
    <p class="name">Robot</p>
    <span class="tag">blue</span>
  </div>
</div>




When you look up the text, you can increase the specificity of the search to only search elements with the name class:
$(this).toggle($(this).find(".name").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)

I added a .find() call to the element which will narrow the scope of the .text() call to only elements with the name class.
